# How to embed sqlite tables to java eclipse application?

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

I have created a Java Payroll app . I have created the sqlite tables and managed to connect them to the app (insert , update etc functions). The main problem is how can I embed these tables to my app , in order to run my app in another computer. Any suggestions or examples?( I have already added the sqlite-driver.jar to my classpath).

Comment: do you want to access the same data, or just load the table structure?

Comment: the main idea is to upload my app in a site and everyone who will download it , will run it locally to his computer for his own bussiness.So , I don't want the same data , only the structure.

Comment: try to add an empty SQLite database file to your project and load it with the library. I dont know which one you are using, so i can't provide any code

Comment: I am using jdbc-api-1.4.jar.

Comment: there is an example https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc#how-to-specify-database-files
I guess you can use a realative file path

Comment: hm , yes . If I understand right I will put my db files in the lib folder of my project. But , in another pc which will have a different path?

Comment: as I said try to use a realtive path